# discord.py how to make requirements.txt

Tags: python, heroku, bots, discord.py, requirements

finally I made my discord bot now I need to upload it to Heroku so it can be online 24/7. I watched some videos about that. youtube guys were using a simple bot code. and their requirements.txt file be like

```
discord
```

yea literally this because their code is so simple. how do I add my other things into that.

top of my code is like

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import os
```

i dont wanna do smth wrong that I cant fix it later because it happens to me a lot :v

Comment: Use `pipreqs`. See: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs

Comment: wow thats really helpfull thing. thanks I will use it on my future projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os is a default python package so it doesn't need to be included. Aside from that you only have discord and youtube_dl so place those in your requirements.txt

```
discord
youtube_dl
```

Comment: I mean how do you do it? how do I decide that ffmpeg shouldnt be included?